# Can't create or view multiple pages of PS file

Tags: ps

New TeXstudio user.  I have used TeXstudio to create an 8 page pdf file.  Trying to submit it to a journal and they require a PS file.  I need help making one.

I am using TeXstudio 2.12.4. I have "PS Chain" selected for Build & View.

I have tried using both "EPS/PS Viewer" and "ghostscript" and despite all my best efforts I can only make a single page (the first page).  That is, when a PS file is generated and I open it, I am only able to see the first page.

Fun Fact: A colleague created and sent me a PS file that was certainly 8 pages (it was submitted and accepted). When I open this document I am only able to view the first page.  Seems like the application I'm using to view the files may not be the best one?

Thanks for reading.  Would really appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a problem of your viewer. When using Ghostscript on Windows: Press Enter inside the "Ghostscript" window to move to the next page in the "Ghostscript Image" window.

Comment: Wonderful.  A real "the files are in the computer" moment.

Comment: I don't suppose you could tell me how to view the next page in "EPS\PS Viewer"?  The images appear sharper with this viewer compared to ghostscript.

Comment: Also, I suppose there is an 'upvote' or something on this site?  If so, let me know and I'll credit you for your effort.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of your viewer.

In Ghostscript you can press Enter inside the "Ghostscript" window to move to the next page in the "Ghostscript Image" window.

With the EPS Viewer from http://epsviewer.org/ (assuming that you use this one) only the first page can be viewed, as this basically seems to be an image viewer, as stated in the [tutorial](http://epsviewer.org/Tutorial.aspx) and inside the feature list.